# UITableView won't show data

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios5

I'm pretty lost right now and have no idea where the problem could be.

I created a single-view application (with ARC & Storyboard), added a tableview to the mainview, set the delegate and datasource of it to my viewcontroller and implemented

```
- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.games count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.games objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    return cell;
}
```

as protocol methods.

`self.games` is an array with some NSStrings.
When I build and run the application, an empty TableView shows up...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `cell.textLabel.text = @"this normal test text"` At first try that.If it works then problem is in your array neither in your `tableview` if not works.At first check it then tell me where is problem?

Comment: It really had something to do with my array.
I set `numberOfRowInSection` to just return 5 and what you suggested and it worked.
I'm initializing my array like this: `self.games = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Red", @"Green",
                @"Blue", @"Indigo", @"Violet", nil];`

(and its a weak nonatomic property), how is that not going to work?

Comment: Actually i wanted to find out where is the problem,`self.games`Array problem or `tableview` problem. according to my question to you, have you got the ultimate result? is `this normal test text` is printing in tableview cell?

Comment: " 
It really had something to do with my array. I set numberOfRowInSection to just return 5 and what you suggested and it worked." - Did you actually read that?

Comment: please post your full tableview delegate and the method where you are allocing the games array.

Comment: I figured out that the NSArray needs to be a strong property, then it works.

Answer (score 2):

Are you setting the delegate source & the data source for your tableView?

You need to conform your class to the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocols. ( `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is in the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol )

Do this by using angle brackets in your class interface definition i.e. in your `.h` file:

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {...}
```

then in your `.m` file you need to set the delegate file owner of the tableView and also the dataSource. this is done like so -

```
[tableView setDelegate:self];
[tableView setDataSource:self];
```

Give this a shot.

Comment: It is conform, I did use those protocols.
And the delegate and datasource I set in the interface Builder.

Comment: then try `[tableView reloadData];` then ios will refresh table content & your code in those delegates will be used.

Comment: Still doesnt work, if I use the array (look comments above), something must be wrong with the array...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try making the games property strong instead of weak? I'm not familiar with ARC, but it seems like your property might be set to nil before you use it.

Comment: I looked into ARC a little bit, and from what I understand, the games property should be strong. You pointed it towards an autoreleased array, and when the method where you did that ends, that array can get released and the games property is set to nil.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing this code.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
```

}